# Send data received on serial port to JavaFX controller

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, serial-port, listener

I'm trying to read data from the serial port and display it in a JavaFX controller. I'm using jSerialComm to read data from the serial port. This is their example:

```
public final class MessageListener implements SerialPortMessageListener {
    @Override
    public int getListeningEvents() { return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED; }

    @Override
    public byte[] getMessageDelimiter() { return new byte[] { (byte) 0x03}; }

    @Override
    public boolean delimiterIndicatesEndOfMessage() { return true; }

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        byte[] delimitedMessage = event.getReceivedData();
        System.out.println("Received the following delimited message: " + new String(delimitedMessage));
    }
}
```

The serial event is then attached to a com port:

```
static public void main(String[] args) {
    SerialPort comPort = SerialPort.getCommPorts()[0];

    comPort.setBaudRate(1200);
    comPort.openPort();
    comPort.addDataListener(new MessageListener());
}
```

In the `serialEvent` method, data is printed in the console. How can I send the data received in this event to a JavaFX controller?

Comment: Just create the same message listener in your JavaFX app, and in the `serialEvent(...)` method do whatever you need to do with the data (append it to a `TextArea`, or whatever). The only thing you may need to do that's different is to manage threading. (I don't know what thread the `serialEvent(...)` method is called on.)

Comment: So should I transform my controller into this message listener by implementing the interface and append my new controller to the comPort, instead of the ```MessageListener```?

Comment: That would work, but I would recommend following the usual OOP principles (single responsibility, etc.).

Comment: Would it work if I sent a reference of the controller to the ```MessageListener``` and call the methods from the ```serialEvent``` method?

Comment: Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: Right, you have a point. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're asking: you already have all the pieces.

I'm not familiar with `jSerialComm` (in particular how it manages threading), but your JavaFX application will look like this:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private SerialPort comPort;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        comPort = SerialPort.getCommPorts()[0];

        comPort.setBaudRate(1200);
        comPort.openPort();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/path/to/fxml/file"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        MyControllerClass controller = loader.getController();

        SerialPortMessageListener listener = new SerialPortMessageListener() {
            @Override
            public int getListeningEvents() { return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED; }

            @Override
            public byte[] getMessageDelimiter() { return new byte[] { (byte)0x03}; }

            @Override
            public boolean delimiterIndicatesEndOfMessage() { return true; }

            @Override
            public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
                byte[] delimitedMessage = event.getReceivedData();
                Platform.runLater(() -> controller.processData(new String(delimitedMessage)));
            }
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // shut down comPort
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyControllerClass {
    @FXML
    private TextArea textArea;

    public void processData(String data) {
        textArea.appendText(data);
    }

    // other controller stuff
}
```